# How can I ensure a parent is deleted when it has no children?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship

In my application I have a 1 - many relationship, which maps "Slots" against "Adverts", such that a advert can be added to multiple slots.

```
Slot (id, location)
Advert (slot_id, text, url)
```

However, when an advert is removed from all slots, I'd also like it to deleted.

I thought the best way of doing this would be to add a check to the `Slot.Advert` setter and to the `Advert.Slots.Remove()` method, such that if the last relationship was being removed, the advert could be deleted;

```
public class Slot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? AdvertId { get; set; }

    private Advert _Advert;
    public virtual Advert Advert
    {
        get
        {
            return _Advert;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_Advert != value && _Advert != null && _Advert.Slots.Count == 1)
            {
                // How do I delete the _Advert here? I have no access to the context? :(
            }

            _Advert = value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, as can be seen above, I haven't got a "context" instance in the `setter`, so I'm not able to delete the Advert.

Whilst I *could* open a new context, doing so

- Feels wrong
- The advert being deleted and a new advert been applied to the slot would not be transactional (happening in two separate context connections).

Does anyone know what options I have? I'm in POCO land and using Entity Framework 6.1

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the `SaveChanges` method for your context.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Advert>().Where(e=>e.Entity.Slots.Count()==0))
    {
        entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: `Foreach` for all `SaveChanges` calls?? Any performance issue?

Comment: How often is SaveChanges called? It's examining in-memory objects. How many `Advert` entities are being tracked at any given time? I wouldn't think it'd be an issue, but of course your mileage may vary.

Comment: @JC: I'm a little unsure how the change tracker will work in this situation; for example, if I did `slot.Advert = null` directly, would this cause the `Advert` to show up in the change tracker (even if I hadn't specifically loaded it into memory; I use lazy loading)?

Comment: That depends how `slot` and its `Advert` navigation property got populated in the first place. If it came from a LinqToEntities query and you're still operating against the context that ran the query then yeah it should still be in memory. Lazy loading will load it into the context's internal sets.